.NET 8 console dependency injection pass data from JSON to class not working
I have the following code and if I run it with line 36 comment removed, I get the data from the .json file into the variable CollarSurveyPickupSettings.
If I then run the cspvm line at row 37 (CollarSurveyPickupVM), it sends the 3 DbContext data loaded, the Options loaded, but no data in CollarSurveyPickupM collarSurveyModel, AcquireCommandLineM acquireCommandLineModel, or PeggingSettingsM peggingModel.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.
I have also added a git repository https://github.com/JemQDev/RHOKSAutomationConsole
program.cs:
using CommandLine;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.CollarSurvey;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.EFACQ;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.EFRHOKS2020;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.EFRHOKS2024;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.Pegging;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.Settings;

namespace RHOKSAutomationConsole;

public class Options
{
    [Option("DataSource", Required = true, Default = "TEST", HelpText = "Data Source as TEST or PROD")]
    public string? DataSource { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    //private static AppM? ApplicationData;
    //private static AcquireCommandLineM? ACQCommandLineData;
    //private static CollarSurveyPickupM? CollarSurveyPickupSettings;
    //private static PeggingSettingsM? PeggingSettings;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
             .WithParsed<Options>(options =>
             {
                 using IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(options).Build();
                 //IConfiguration config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                 //CollarSurveyPickupSettings = config.GetSection("CollarSurveyPickups").Get<CollarSurveyPickupM>() ?? new CollarSurveyPickupM();
                 var cspvm = host.Services.GetRequiredService<CollarSurveyPickupVM>();
             });
    }

    #region HostBuilder
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(Options optionsq) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config
            .AddJsonFile(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\Settings\\appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\Settings\\SerilogSettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddConfiguration(context.Configuration)
            .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            IConfiguration config = hostContext.Configuration;

            //services.Configure<AppSettingsM>(options => config.GetSection("ApplicationSettings").Bind(options));
            services.Configure<SerilogSettingsM>(options => config.GetSection("Serilog").Bind(options));
            services.Configure<AcquireCommandLineM>(options => config.GetSection("SECRET_ACQ_Credentials").Bind(options));
            services.Configure<CollarSurveyPickupM>(options => config.GetSection("CollarSurveyPickups").Bind(options));
            services.Configure<PeggingSettingsM>(options => config.GetSection("OreDefPegging").Bind(options));

            services.AddDbContext<RHOKS_2020Context>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    $"Data Source=" +
                    $"{config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:VM.SQL:SQLServer").Get<string>()}" +
                    $"\\" +
                    $"{config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:VM.SQL:SQLInstance").Get<string>()};" +
                    $"Initial Catalog={config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:VM.SQL:SQLDatabaseRHOKS2020").Get<string>()}" +
                    $";Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;", x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            services.AddDbContext<RHOKS_2024Context>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    $"Data Source=" +
                    $"{config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:VM.SQL:SQLServer").Get<string>()}" +
                    $"\\" +
                    $"{config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:VM.SQL:SQLInstance").Get<string>()};" +
                    $"Initial Catalog={config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:VM.SQL:SQLDatabaseRHOKS2024").Get<string>()}" +
                    $";Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;", x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            services.AddDbContext<ACQContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    $"Data Source=" +
                    $"{config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:ACQ.SQL:SQLServer").Get<string>()}" +
                    $"\\" +
                    $"{config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:ACQ.SQL:SQLInstance").Get<string>()};" +
                    $"Initial Catalog={config.GetSection("SqlConfigurations:ACQ.SQL:SQLDatabaseACQ").Get<string>()}" +
                    $";Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;", x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            services.AddSingleton<Options>(optionsq);

            services.AddSingleton<AppM>();

            services.AddSingleton<AcquireCommandLineM>();
            services.AddSingleton<PeggingSettingsM>();

            services.AddSingleton<CollarSurveyPickupM>();
            services.AddSingleton<CollarSurveyPickupVM>();
    }

    //.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
    //.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
    //.ReadFrom.Services(services)
    );
    #endregion HostBuilder
}

CollarSurveyPickupVM:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.EFACQ;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.EFRHOKS2020;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.EFRHOKS2024;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.Pegging;
using RHOKSAutomationConsole.Settings;
using System.Globalization;

namespace RHOKSAutomationConsole.CollarSurvey;

public partial class CollarSurveyPickupVM : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] CollarSurveyPickupM? m_CollarSurveyPickupSettings;
    [ObservableProperty] AcquireCommandLineM? m_AcquireCommandLineModel;
    [ObservableProperty] Options m_OptionsData;
    [ObservableProperty] RHOKS_2024Context m_Rhoks2024Context;
    [ObservableProperty] RHOKS_2020Context m_Rhoks2020Context;
    [ObservableProperty] ACQContext m_AcquireContext;

    public CollarSurveyPickupVM(
        RHOKS_2024Context rhoks2024context,
        RHOKS_2020Context rhoks2020context,
        ACQContext acquirecontext,
        Options options,
        CollarSurveyPickupM? collarSurveyModel,
        AcquireCommandLineM acquireCommandLineModel,
        PeggingSettingsM peggingModel
        )
    {
        Rhoks2024Context = rhoks2024context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rhoks2024context));
        Rhoks2020Context = rhoks2020context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rhoks2020context));
        AcquireContext = acquirecontext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(acquirecontext));
        OptionsData = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        PeggingModel = peggingModel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(peggingModel));
        AcquireCommandLineModel = acquireCommandLineModel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(acquireCommandLineModel));
        CollarSurveyPickupSettings = collarSurveyModel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collarSurveyModel));
    }

    public PeggingSettingsM PeggingModel { get; }
}


You are registering your option models:
services.Configure<CollarSurveyPickupM>(options => config.GetSection("CollarSurveyPickups").Bind(options));

and registering them as normal injectable services as well (not sure why as singletons (?), read more about lifetimes here)
services.AddSingleton<CollarSurveyPickupM>();

So when you inject them as normal services, you'll get them resolved as normal services:
public CollarSurveyPickupVM(CollarSurveyPickupM collarSurveyModel)
{
    CollarSurveyPickupSettings = collarSurveyModel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collarSurveyModel));
}

To inject them as options bind against IConfiguration you need to inject them as such. So, as IOptions<T>:
public CollarSurveyPickupVM(IOptions<CollarSurveyPickupM> collarSurveyModelOptions)
{
    CollarSurveyPickupSettings = collarSurveyModelOptions?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collarSurveyModelOptions));
}

You can also simplify your option registration calls by passing the configuration section to the Configure() call, omitting the action delegate. It will have the same result; options for CollarSurveyPickupM type will be registered to bind against the "CollarSurveyPickups" section:
services.Configure<CollarSurveyPickupM>(config.GetSection("CollarSurveyPickups"));

Final note
Your code suffers from mixing up of service layers and models. You should separate those. Use services for business logic and models for data transportation. I'm not an expert in MVVM architecture, but I'm sure enough that models should not act as both and have DI slapped on top of that.
Finally, it is worth a read: Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core

Thank you Prolog.
It works fine now and what you explained now make sense..
The fix was the IOptions<> in the VM. The rest of it (injecting as normal services) was just for me to try and figure out if it was working the program.cs and why it was not passing into the VM. But I see it was unnecessary.
I am looking at the link you sent and trying to learn more.
Much appreciated.
